# Google Analytics for SDK iOS - implementing automatic screen

Tags: ios, google-analytics

I want to add google analytics to my application, I followed up the instructions in this link https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/#screen-tracking

I did all the instructions, my question is in the last step when I want to measure with a view controller, my view controller .h is :

```
@interface RootViewController : UIViewController<SectionHeaderViewDelegate, UITableViewDelegate,UIAlertViewDelegate>
```

in the instructions given in the link above, they said that we have to import `#import "GAITrackedViewController.h"` and we have to update the header like :

```
@interface RootViewController : GAITrackedViewController

@end
```

my question is shall I update the `UIViewController` from `@interface RootViewController : UIViewController<SectionHeaderViewDelegate, UITableViewDelegate,UIAlertViewDelegate>`
to 
`@interface RootViewController : GAITrackedViewController<SectionHeaderViewDelegate, UITableViewDelegate,UIAlertViewDelegate>` ????

please help! 
Many thanks.

Comment: if it bothers u, u can send it through programatically.. without changing to GAITrackedViewController

Comment: Summary From the accepted Answer: Use **Manual Screen Measurement**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

You need to change the inheritance from plain UIViewController to the Google tracked view controller and you need to keep all of your protocol information as well (the things in <>)

Comment: ok got it, but in my app I have views that they are inherited from UITableViewController, and I want to measure their analytics, in this case what shall I do? please advise!!!

Comment: You will need to use manual screen measurement for a UITableViewController - https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/screens

Comment: should I put default tracker in `id tracker = [[GAI sharedInstance] defaultTracker];` or my tracker id instead, I already put my tracker id in the app delegate, so what is the default tracker in the manual measurement serve for?

Comment: You send two things - the tracker and the screen name.  Typically the tracker is the same throughout your app, but the screen name will be different e.g. "Main screen", "Settings", "My Table View" etc.  You can use multiple trackers if you want to specifically capture sections of your app under a different tracker in Google Analytics

Comment: yes, understood, by my question is regarding the default tracker? shouldn't I put my tracker ID instead the default tracker?

Comment: In your app delegate you should have `[[GAI sharedInstance] trackerWithTrackingId:@"UA-XXXX-Y"];`  Then, when you use `[[GAI sharedInstance] defaultTracker];` you will get back UA-XXXX-Y (Whatever you used to initialise the GAI instance).  This is so you only need to set your tracker ID in one place in your app and if you ever need to change it, it is only in one place.

Comment: that is what i did, I put in my delegate my tracker id `[[GAI sharedInstance] trackerWithTrackingId:@"UA-XXXX-Y"];` and in another view when i am using the manual measurement, i put `   id tracker = [[GAI sharedInstance] defaultTracker];
    NSLog(@"%@", tracker);` but it doesn't log my tracker id, it logs `<GAITrackerImpl: 0xcc6b220>`

Comment: The description method for Google's GAITracker doesn't return the tracker as a string, it just returns what you are seeing in the log - the object's type and address, but it will be the correct tracker value